# Trace query that get query processor ran out of internal resources

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In the event log we get the error

```
The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer Support Services for more information.

Its a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) 
    Apr  2 2010 15:48:46 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

I need to catch what is causing the problem. It's the only option to set up a sql server trace to get the errors? Or are the any startup parameters to the server that i can use? Or alternative method. That not effects the servers performance or need a restart of the server.

Comment: You can refer below link that might help you.http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28945/query-processor-ran-out-of-internal-resources-and-could-not-produce-a-query-plan

Comment: Let me guess, you use ORM like (EF) and IN clause hit limit of query length.

Answer (score 0):

We solved it checking the event log on all calling application servers for the error. After that we find the system that was causing the error and contacted the vendor of the problem.